# "Let $R$ be an integral domain. Assuming that the Division Algorithm holds in $R[x]$, prove that $R$ is a field."

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

> Let $R$ be an integral domain. Assuming that the Division Algorithm holds in $R[x]$, prove that $R$ is a field.

Can someone tell me if I am going about proving this correctly? My tactic was going to be to prove that every integral domain that works with the Division Algorithm (so I guess a Euclidean Domain) is finite, and thus would be a finite ring, which would make it a field based on the theorem that states just that. I don't know if this is valid logic, so could someone tell me if I'm at least on the right path?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Great first question. Observe that the integers are an integral domain and a euclidean domain, but they're not finite!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with  ‘works with division algorithm’?

Comment: If $R[X]$ is a PID consider the ideal generated by $a\neq 0$ in $R$ and $X$...